# how to get the id of a selected item using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My objective is to get the id of a selected item from the dropdown. I could not able to get the id of the respective item.

here is the array looks like

```
[
{
id: "sdfgh47ddtrgy_8dfstdf"
name: "Orange"
},
{
id: "qwert47ddtrgy_8dfstdf"
name: "Apple"
},
{
id: "ufnhur18fgve_8dfstdf"
name: "Banana"
},
]
```

I have assigned to the state variable: fruits: []

In dropdown i've maped in this way:

```
{this.state.fruits.map((fruit) =>
 <MenuItem value={fruit.name} key={fruit.id}>{fruit.name}</MenuItem>
)}
```

OnChange method:

```
OnChange = (e)=> {
 let value = this.state.fruits.filter((item) => item.id == e.target.value)
 console.log("Value", value)
}
```

i'm getting an empty array. Can anyone help me where i'm going wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example, i.e. what is rendering the fruits and has the onChange handler?

Comment: <MenuItem value={fruit.name} key={fruit.id}>{fruit.name}</MenuItem> i think that you should change this one to <MenuItem value={fruit.id} key={fruit.id}>{fruit.name}</MenuItem> you are puting name on value and taking it

Comment: What is the value of `e` that you are getting? Is it a json or an event object?

Comment: As @NurbekBoymurodov says above, or just add an additional `id` prop?

Comment: If you're going to compare items to check if they match please use "===" instead of "=="

Comment: you are comparing `id` with `name`.  --> value={fruit.name}

Comment: @NurbekBoymurodov - after modifying, i'm getting one object in array

Comment: @Sandhya what is value of e that you are getting?

Comment: also I think to get one object is answer you wanted right?

Comment: @NurbekBoymurodov - I'm getting error sometimes.. i could not do setState for the id

Comment: @Sheelpriy - I didn't get you

Comment: In `onChange` function `e.target.value` will have `fruit.name` and you are comparing this with `fruit.id` in your filter callback.   `name==id` will always be false. hence you are getting an empty array. Either change in filter callback or in `MenuItem` value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
 {this.state.fruits.map((fruit) =>
    <MenuItem value={fruit.name} key={fruit.id}>{fruit.name} 
    </MenuItem>
 )}
```

TO:

```
{this.state.fruits.map((fruit) =>
  <MenuItem value={fruit.id} key={fruit.id}>{fruit.name} 
  </MenuItem>
)}
```

and onChange will be:

```
OnChange =(e)=> {
 let value = this.state.fruits.filter(item => item.id === e.target.value)
 console.log("Value", value)
}
```

try this. it should work.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you use custom select that is mimicking the native select item, and the `onChange` is on the parent component u should do it like so:

```
{this.state.fruits.map((fruit) =>
   <MenuItem value={fruit.id/* important*/} key={fruit.id}>{fruit.name} </MenuItem>
)}
```

the onChange:

```
OnChange = (e)=> {
   let value = e.target.value
   console.log("Value", value)
}
```